# How to select an element by distance when it isn't a parent or child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I'm working on editing a tooltip plugin (TooltipsY) to use a div instead of the title element for the content of the tooltip. I'm doing this for a multitude of reasons, the primary one being so I can have HTML in my tooltips without causing validation errors.

The problem I'm having is that when changed the content of the tooltip to be the div instead of the title attribute, every link with a tooltip shows the same tooltip content. That's because The div's aren't related to the links in any way so I can't use "this" to select them.

It would work if I knew some way to change `$('div.showtip').html();` to `this.closest($('div.showtip').html());` (that method won't work because the div isn't a parent or a child of the link) so how can I make the tooltip content the closest div to the link that's being hovered over?

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/sgCCD/2/

**Note:** The only thing that should need to be changed is the value of the variable showtip.

Also, I don't want a suggestion for a different tooltip plugin, I'm doing this just as much for my own personal experience as I am to improve the functionality of the plugin.

Comment: Your example doesn't show the problem, please update it so that we can see what's happening.

Comment: Oh, ugg, I forgot to update it =S I lost a lot of work >:(

Comment: Oh wait, gotta fix one more thing I did earlier and deleted =p

Comment: Ok, now it should be pretty clear what the problem is and what to do to fix it (given that you are able)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/sgCCD/3/

changed this line:

`var showtip = $('div.showtip').html();`

to this:

`var showtip = $(el).next().html();`

Comment: Thank you very much. Good idea about the "next" I would've done that myself if I knew more about jQuery but I'm a newbie. But that was the obvious choice. I did make one fix though.

Comment: I changed it so instead of using `next()` it uses `nextAll('.showtip')` that way it finds the next element with the class showtip in the document and uses that. (I imagined that would be a lot more specific and would avoid things I didn't want showing up in the tooltip)

Comment: Here is my fix: http://jsfiddle.net/sgCCD/5/ (I didn't upvote so you might get the unsung hero badge, if you want me to upvote let me know)

Comment: Good catch, I wasn't sure what the structure of the tooltip was going to be.

Comment: Yeah, as soon as I looked at your changes I was looking for where you referenced the .showtip and then I realised you didn't, you were just whatever element came after the .hastip. So I had to fix that ;p

Comment: by the way, I have sent these changes to Brian Cray, the person who wrote tooltipsy and hopefully our changes will be implemented to the next version of tooltipsy

Comment: Yeah, this is why I love web developing and programming; the community is so great :D